# Prestashop var in sql query

Tags: sql, prestashop

I need to get customers list WHERE date_add > $select_date

With this I can output selected date:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('select_date' , Configuration::get('SELECT_DATE'));
```

So var: select_date and value: SELECT_DATE (its input type="date")

```
sql = 'SELECT firstname,lastname FROM ps_customers WHERE date_add >= ("2014-07-21")';
```

With this query it works perfect.

If I use:

```
sql = 'SELECT firstname,lastname FROM ps_customers WHERE date_add >= $select_date';
```

I just get error: PrestaShopDatabaseException - Unknown column '$select_date' in 'where clause'.

So it seems I cant use my vars in sql query, so how to make this to work correct?

Also I think maybe its better to get all clients in ARRAY and use condition in TPL file to print only date which >= {$select_date} but how to write such condition?

```
{foreach $custdata as $item}
        <tr >
            <td style="text-align:center;">{$item.firstname}</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">{$item.lastname} </td>

            <td style="text-align:center;">{$item.date_add} </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In php, if you have a string in single quotes, then you can't use a variable in it directly, like :

```
sql = 'SELECT firstname,lastname FROM ps_customers WHERE date_add >= $select_date';
```

There are two ways to use a variable in a string as below :

1) Concatenate the variable to the string if single quotes :

```
sql = 'SELECT firstname,lastname FROM ps_customers WHERE date_add >= '.$select_date;
```

2) Use double quotes :

```
sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname FROM ps_customers WHERE date_add >= $select_date";
```

Also for double quotes, you can concatenate the variable, it will be fine.

Comment: Altough this is the real reason why asker's query isn't working, still remember to ***always escape the input if it is from unreliable source*** (like user, etc...) ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an escape string first:

```
$select_date = pSql($select_date);
```

And then use the $select_date variable in SQL